# Why am I getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'john' of undefined

Tags: javascript, object

I am new to JavaScript and may not be using correct terms so please bear with me.

http://jsbin.com/IPaDAJO/1/

I am expect the following be displayed on the page
Hello my name is John Smith and I am 29 years old. Hello my name is Suzie Alport and I am 24 years old.

I want to understand why can't Suzie refer to John's greet method?

```
<script>
        var employees = {
            john: {
                name: "John Smith",
                age: 29,
                job: "web developer",
                greet: function(){
                    document.write("Hello my name is " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age + " years old. ");
                }
            },
            suzie: {
                name: "Suzie Alport",
                age: 24,
                job: "nursery assistant",
                greet: employees.john.greet
            }
        };
        employees.john.greet();
        employees.suzie.greet();
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: read up on variable `scope` and `this` in JavaScript

Comment: @shennan: This has nothing to do with scope or `this`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was taking a wild guess as errors like that are usually the result of scope issues for me. This was before he put the code snippet up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the time that you're creating the object you're assigning to the `suzie` property, `employees` is `undefined`. The property initializers are evaluated before the overall expression is complete.

Here's the order in which things happen above:

1. The engine creates a variable called `employees` with the initial value `undefined`.
2. The engine creates a blank object (which will eventually be assigned to `employees`).
3. The engine creates another blank object (which will eventually become the `john` property value).
4. It evaluates `"John Smith"` and creates a property on the blank object from #3 called `name`, giving it that value.
5. It repeats that process for `age`, `job`, and `greet`.
6. It assigns that object to the `john` property on the object from #2 above.
7. It creates another blank object (to become `suzie`).
8. It evaluates `"Suzie Alport"` and creates a property on the object from #7 called `name`, giving it that value.
9. It repeats the process for `age` and `job`.
10. It tries to evaluate the expression `employees.john.greet` and fails because `employees` is `undefined`.

If you break it into two pieces, it works (until `document.write` blows things up):

```
var employees = {
    john: {
        name: "John Smith",
        age: 29,
        job: "web developer",
        greet: function(){
            document.write("Hello my name is " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age + " years old. ");
        }
    }
};
employees.suzie = {
    name: "Suzie Alport",
    age: 24,
    job: "nursery assistant",
    greet: employees.john.greet
};
employees.john.greet();
employees.suzie.greet();
```

That works because before we try to evaluate `employees.john.greet`, a reference to the object created in #2 above has been assigned to the `employees` variable.

---

Side note:

Avoid using `document.write` in modern web pages and applications. Instead, use [DOM methods](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR). `document.write` only works the way you likely want it to during the *initial* page load; after initial page load, it will wipe out the existing document entirely and start writing a new document in the same window.

For instance, you can append paragraphs to the `document.body` like this:

```
function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IPaDAJO/6) with both of the above ([source](http://jsbin.com/IPaDAJO/6/edit))

Comment: Thanks, is there a typo in one of your steps. Should step 8 read: It evaluates "Suzie Alport" and creates a property on the object from ** #7 ** called name, giving it that value.

Comment: @Abdi: Thanks. When I inserted step 1 (which I nearly forgot!) I could have sworn there were two places I needed to update, but I only found one. That was the other one. :-)